# Transformation in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So im doing transformations and for example if we were to write:

$$y = x^3$$

and then shift it to the **left by $4$** it would be written as

$$y = (x - 4)^3$$

so how come in another problem I have, $y=-3f(x-2)$, the $"(x-2)"$ in this equation means it will move to the right by $2$? Isn't it suppose to move to the left since it's $-2$ and not a $+2$?

Comment: Compare the graphs of $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = f(x - 2) = (x - 2)^2$. What are the zeros of each, so how must the parabola have been shifted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Movement to the left means that the amount of movement has to be **added**. So if you shift $y=x^3$ to the **left by 4** places, you will get the graph $y=(x+4)^3$ (to see this, look at how the roots have shifted when you shift the graph). In the other problem, $y=-3f(x-2)$, it turns out that the graph $y=-3f(x)$ has been shifted two places to the **right**, and not the left.

> Key point : Movement to the left, then you add the movement. Movement to the >right, then you subtract the movement.

As an exercise, think about what happens to the equation when you shift the graph up or down.

Comment: ty, it makes sense now.